# In a Python object, how can I see a list of properties that have been defined with the @property decorator?

Tags: python, properties

I can see first-class member variables using `self.__dict__`, but I'd like also to see a dictionary of properties, as defined with the [@property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) decorator.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could add a function to your class that looks something like this:

```
def properties(self):
    # class_items = self.__class__.__dict__.iteritems()  # Python 2
    class_items = self.__class__.__dict__.items()
    return dict((k, getattr(self, k)) 
                for k, v in class_items 
                if isinstance(v, property))
```

This looks for any properties in the class and then creates a dictionary with an entry for each property with the current instance's value.

Comment: Be aware that this only lists properties declared on the class itself IIRC.  Properties of superclasses will not be listed.

Comment: You can walk self.__class__.mro() to find parent classes.

Comment: A one-liner would be `return {k: getattr(self, k) for k, v in self.__class__.__dict__.iteritems() if isinstance(v, property)}`

Comment: for python 3, replace iteritems() with items()

Answer (score 8):

The properties are part of the class, not the instance. So you need to look at `self.__class__.__dict__` or equivalently `vars(type(self))`

So the properties would be

```
[k for k, v in vars(type(self)).items() if isinstance(v, property)]
```

Answer (score 4):

As [user2357112-supports-monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) points out in a comment to a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825035/get-all-properties-from-a-python-class?noredirect=1#comment116383492_65825035), the accepted answer only gets those properties directly defined on the class, missing inherited properties. In order to fix this, we also need to walk over the parent classes:

```
from typing import List


def own_properties(cls: type) -> List[str]:
    return [
        key
        for key, value in cls.__dict__.items()
        if isinstance(value, property)
    ]

def properties(cls: type) -> List[str]:
    props = []
    for kls in cls.mro():
        props += own_properties(kls)
    
    return props
```

For example:

```
class GrandparentClass:
    @property
    def grandparent_prop(self):
        return "grandparent_prop"   


class ParentClass(GrandparentClass):
    @property
    def parent_prop(self):
        return "parent"


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    @property
    def child_prop(self):
        return "child"


properties(ChildClass)  # ['child_prop', 'parent_prop', 'grandparent_prop']
```

If you need to get the properties of an instance, simply pass `instance.__class__` to `get_properties`

Comment: You should traverse `cls.__mro__` instead of recursing over `cls.__bases__`, to handle diamond inheritance properly. Recursing over `cls.__bases__` may visit some ancestors repeatedly.

Comment: This was also pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876049/in-a-python-object-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-properties-that-have-been-defined-wi/65825416#comment17809207_5876258

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, yes. You are right. I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For an object f, this gives the list of members that are properties:

```
[n for n in dir(f) if isinstance(getattr(f.__class__, n), property)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir(obj)` gives a list of all attributes of `obj`, including methods and attributes.

Comment: Right, but I need to know the properties specifically.  I considered overwriting the `@property` decorator to add them to a registry on `obj`, but I figured Python probably has a fancy `__something__` that already does this.