# Check if class property has a setter

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I need to list all the attribute of a class that are properties and have a setter. For example with this class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self. a = 1
        self._b = 2
        self._c = 3

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self._c = value
```

I need to get the attribute c but not a and b.
Using this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876258/7529716
i can get the property object b and c.

But is their a way to know if those properties have a setter other than trying:

```
inst = MyClass()    
try:
    prev = inst.b
    inst.b = None
except AttributeError:
    pass # No setter
finally:
    inst.b = prev
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking for forgiveness rather than permission is a common coding style in python. Is there a reason you're keen to avoid it?

Comment: Some  of my setter do modification that are not renversable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`property` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) store their getter, setter and deleter in the `fget`, `fset` and `fdel` attributes, respectively. If a property doesn't have a setter or deleter, the attribute is set to `None`.

This means you can simply filter out those properties whose `fset` attribute is set to `None`:

```
def get_writeable_properties(cls):
    return [attr for attr, value in vars(cls).items()
                 if isinstance(value, property) and value.fset is not None]
```

```
>>> get_writeable_properties(MyClass)
['c']
```

Comment: You can make this even better and support not only class arguments but also instances. You would get the `obj.__class__` if `inspect.isclass(obj)` yields `False`

Comment: @MatiasCicero I don't think that's a good idea, because of metaclasses. Classes are also instances. I don't like to guess what the user wants; I'd rather write a function that only works on classes or only on instances.