# Get all @properties from a Python Class

Tags: python, properties, code-inspection

In Python, how can I get all *properties* of a class, i.e. all members created by the `@property` decorator?

There are at least two questions<sup>[1, 2]</sup> on stackoverflow which confound the terms *property* and *attribute*, falsely taking *property* as a synonym for *attribute*, which is misleading in Python context. So, even though the other questions' titles might suggest it, they do not answer my question.

---

[1]: [Print all properties of a Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969806/print-all-properties-of-a-python-class)
[2]: [Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a)

Answer (score 0):

We can get all *attributes* of a class `cls` by using `cls.__dict__`. Since `property` is a certain class itself, we can check which attributes of `cls` are an instance of `property`:

```
from typing import List


def properties(cls: type) -> List[str]:
    return [
        key
        for key, value in cls.__dict__.items()
        if isinstance(value, property)
    ]
```

Comment: That's not going to find inherited properties. You need to traverse the whole MRO.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Good point. Thanks for the hint. This was missing in the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876049/in-a-python-object-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-properties-that-have-been-defined-wi as well, so I posted an answer there.