# Is there a way to avoid boilerplate property getters in Python subclasses using the @property decorator?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, properties

I am trying to create subclasses of some superclass that has properties (delineated by the `property` decorator) and a `properties()` method that returns the properties and their values as a `dict`. I want the subclasses to be able to make use of the inherited `properties()` method with minimal boilerplate code needing to be copied and pasted into each subclass definition. I'm using Python 3.8 if it makes a difference here.

The emphasis here is on the *boilerplate* code that I want to refactor.

I begin with a simple class, `BaseClass`, defined as follows:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self._A = A
        self._B = B
    
    @property
    def A(self):
        return self._A
    
    @A.setter
    def A(self, new_value):
        # ... Validate input ...
        self._A = new_value

    @property
    def B(self):
        return self._B

    @B.setter
    def B(self, new_value):
        # ... Validate input ...
        self._B = new_value

    def properties(self):
        class_items = self.__class__.__dict__.items()
        return dict((k, getattr(self, k)) for k, v in class_items if isinstance(v, property))
```

I should note that I defined the `properties()` method at the end after reading [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876258/22653361).

Example usage of `BaseClass` as defined above:

```
>>> base_instance = BaseClass('foo','bar')
>>> base_instance.properties()
{'A': 'foo', 'B': 'bar'}
```

From there, I want to create some subclasses that inherit from `BaseClass` and have the `properties()` method work the same way. Consider the following:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        super().__init__(A, B)
```

But this doesn't behave the way I expected:

```
>>> sub_instance = SubClass('spam',10)
>>> sub_instance.A  # works as expected
'spam'
>>> sub_instance.B  # works as expected
10
>>> sub_instance.properties()  # expected {'A': 'spam', 'B': 10}
{}
```

**I know that the following alternative subclass definition produces the behavior I expected**:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        super().__init__(A, B)

    @BaseClass.A.getter    #
    def A(self):           #  This is all boilerplate
        return self._A     #  that I need to copy and
                           #  paste in every subclass
    @BaseClass.B.getter    #  of BaseClass I define...
    def B(self):           #
        return self._B     #
```

```
>>> sub_instance = SubClass('spam',10)
>>> sub_instance.properties()
{'A': 'spam', 'B': 10}
```

Is there a cleaner way to define properties (with the `property` decorator) inside the superclass `BaseClass` so that the `properties()` method "just works", without the need for the boilerplate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`inspect.getmro`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) to get all base classes:

```py
from inspect import getmro


class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self._A = A
        self._B = B

    @property
    def A(self):
        return self._A

    @A.setter
    def A(self, new_value):
        self._A = new_value

    @property
    def B(self):
        return self._B

    @B.setter
    def B(self, new_value):
        self._B = new_value

    def properties(self):
        out = {}
        for klass in getmro(self.__class__):
            class_items = klass.__dict__.items()
            for k, v in class_items:
                if isinstance(v, property):
                    out[k] = getattr(self, k)
        return out


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        super().__init__(A, B)

    @property
    def C(self):
        return 42


sub_instance = SubClass("spam", 10)
print(sub_instance.properties())
```

Prints:

```
{'C': 42, 'A': 'spam', 'B': 10}
```

Comment: I've decided to go with a variant of this, with `out = {}` followed by `out.update()` in a loop. (I don't want a list of the property names, I want a dict mapping the properties to their values.)

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the way you define `properties` to walk the whole MRO:

```
def properties(self):
    klasses = reversed(type(self).mro())
    return {
        k: getattr(self, k) 
        for klass in klasses 
        for k, v in klass.items() 
        if isinstance(v, property)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To somewhat reduce the boiler plate code of properties, you could create function to automatically implement storage to and retrieval from the specified internal variable.

```
def autoProperty(varName):
    g = dict()
    exec(f"def getProp(self): return self.{varName}",g)
    exec(f"def setProp(self,value): self.{varName} = value",g)
    return property(g["getProp"],g["setProp"])
```

Using this function you can define read/write properties with a single line and you can use it as a decorator (with the `.setter` suffix) when you need special processing on assignment:

```
class BaseClass:

    A = autoProperty("_A")
    
    @autoProperty("_B").setter
    def B(self,value):
        print("changing B to",value)
        self._B = value
        
    def __init__(self,A,B):
        self._A = A
        self._B = B

    def properties(self):
        return { name:getattr(self,name) for name in dir(self.__class__)
                 if isinstance(getattr(self.__class__,name),property) }
```

This will produce the list of properties in your `properties()` method.

```
base_instance = BaseClass('foo','bar')
print(base_instance.properties())

{'A': 'foo', 'B': 'bar'}
```

*Note that I used `dir()` instead of `__class__.__dict__` because the subclasses will not have the superclass's property names in their `__dict__`*

When defining a sub class, you can add more properties using the same approach:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):

    C = autoProperty("_C")
    
    def __init__(self,A,B):
        super().__init__(A,B)
        self._C = A + "-" + B
```

The `properties()` method now accesses the cumulative properties of both the sub and super class:

```
sub_instance = SubClass('spam','10')
print(sub_instance.properties())

{'A': 'spam', 'B': '10', 'C': 'spam-10'}
```